# center an item in a div by ignoring other elements

Tags: html, css

I want to create a header bar and center my title / logo but it's not centered perfectly.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: black;
}

.link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#header {
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #000000;
}

#headerTitleContainer {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#headerTitle {
  color: #97d700;
}

#menuBtnContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

@media (min-width: 300px) {
  #menuBtnContainer {
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 299px) {
  #menuBtnContainer {
    margin-left: 5px;
  }
}

.menuIconBar {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  margin: 6px 0 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
  background-color: #97d700;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="menuBtnContainer">
    <div class="menuIconBar" id="menuIconBar1"></div>
    <div class="menuIconBar" id="menuIconBar2"></div>
    <div class="menuIconBar" id="menuIconBar3"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="headerTitleContainer">
    <h1><a class="link" id="headerTitle" href="/">MyTitle</a></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see `MyTitle` is not centered correctly. How can I do this? I achieve it when taking out my menu button but obviously I need this button. I just want it to be always in the center of the bar. But it should not overlap the menu button.

That's why I added a `margin-right: 10px;` to my menu button.

Comment: if you want `<h1 style="margin-left: -50px;">` you can try this one

Comment: sorry, I want a margin-left of 50%

Comment: i think you use ` position: fixed ` to menu icon like : https://jsfiddle.net/xg5x8jmp/4/   this is right way

Comment: @lalitbhakuni pay attenting with `position:fixed` it ill be fixed on scroll to

Comment: sorry it's `position: absolute` https://jsfiddle.net/xg5x8jmp/4/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution it to make width of button 0 and have `overflow:visible` on it:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: black;
}

.link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#header {
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #000000;
}

#headerTitleContainer {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#headerTitle {
  color: #97d700;
}

#menuBtnContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 0;
  overflow: visible;
}

@media (min-width: 300px) {
  #menuBtnContainer {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right:-20px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 299px) {
  #menuBtnContainer {
    margin-left: 5px;
  }
}

.menuIconBar {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  margin: 6px 0 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
  background-color: #97d700;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="menuBtnContainer">
    <div class="menuIconBar" id="menuIconBar1"></div>
    <div class="menuIconBar" id="menuIconBar2"></div>
    <div class="menuIconBar" id="menuIconBar3"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="headerTitleContainer">
    <h1><a class="link" id="headerTitle" href="/">MyTitle</a></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or simply make the button absolute position without chaging any other property and don't forget to make the parent `position:relative` (I prefer this one):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: black;
}

.link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#header {
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #000000;
  position:relative;
}

#headerTitleContainer {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#headerTitle {
  color: #97d700;
}

#menuBtnContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}

@media (min-width: 300px) {
  #menuBtnContainer {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right:-20px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 299px) {
  #menuBtnContainer {
    margin-left: 5px;
  }
}

.menuIconBar {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  margin: 6px 0 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
  background-color: #97d700;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="menuBtnContainer">
    <div class="menuIconBar" id="menuIconBar1"></div>
    <div class="menuIconBar" id="menuIconBar2"></div>
    <div class="menuIconBar" id="menuIconBar3"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="headerTitleContainer">
    <h1><a class="link" id="headerTitle" href="/">MyTitle</a></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another solution is to add a third hidden element using `:after` taking the same width as the button so the title get centered :

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: black;
}

.link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#header {
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #000000;
}

#header:after {
  content: "";
  width: 35px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#headerTitleContainer {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#headerTitle {
  color: #97d700;
}

#menuBtnContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

@media (min-width: 300px) {
  #menuBtnContainer {
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
  #header:after {
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 299px) {
  #menuBtnContainer {
    margin-left: 5px;
  }
}

.menuIconBar {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  margin: 6px 0 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
  background-color: #97d700;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="menuBtnContainer">
    <div class="menuIconBar" id="menuIconBar1"></div>
    <div class="menuIconBar" id="menuIconBar2"></div>
    <div class="menuIconBar" id="menuIconBar3"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="headerTitleContainer">
    <h1><a class="link" id="headerTitle" href="/">MyTitle</a></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: using position absolute seems to be the way to go

Comment: @StormRage i added a third solution too ;)

Comment: Yah I saw it, but adding a pseudoelement to push the item, it seems a little bit hacky to me, using absolute looks more clean to me.

Comment: But, for general knowledge, it's nice to understand how flex distributes space among its children.

Comment: @StormRage yes sure, but i think in this case space will not help a lot (unless i consider the 3rd solution and use flex:1 with title for example). But since he's playing with margin:auto i think he's aware about how flex handle spaces ;)